# React SSR router - redux state loss when navigating to sub route

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, server-side-rendering

I'm rendering react on the server everything works fine except when navigating to sub routes, redux losses state and data from backend do not appear. The data shows in store in the redux dev tools. The state does not get lost on page refresh however.

Here is an example showing what I mean:

```
website.com/category/books to website.com/category/toys
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen'
import CategoryScreen from './Screens/CategoryScreen'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' component={HomeScreen} exact />
      <Route path='/category/:name' component={CategoryScreen} />
    </Switch>

  )
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { hydrate } from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import store from './store'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'

hydrate(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

store.js:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { productListReducer } from './reducers/productReducers'
import { categoryListReducer } from './reducers/categoryReducers'

const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    categoryList: categoryListReducer,
})

const initialState = {}

const middleware = [thunk]

const loadState = () => {
    try {
        const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state')
        if (serializedState === null) {
            return undefined
        }
        return JSON.parse(serializedState)
    } catch (e) {
        return undefined
    }
}

const saveState = (state) => {
    try {
        const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state)
        localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState)
    } catch (e) {

    }
}

const persistedState = loadState()

const store = createStore(
    reducer, persistedState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

store.subscribe(() => {
    saveState(store.getState())
})

export default store
```

frontend server.js for SSR:

```
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from '../src/store'
import App from '../src/App'
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware'

const PORT = 3000
const app = express()

app.use('/api/products', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://98.51.100.255:5000', changeOrigin: true }))
app.use('/api/categories', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://98.51.100.255:5000', changeOrigin: true }))

const router = express.Router()

const serverRenderer = (req, res, next) => {

  app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'), function (err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      }
    })
  })

  const context = {}

  fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return res.status(500).send('An error occurred')
    }
    return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">
        ${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
              <App />
            </StaticRouter>
          </Provider>
        )}
        </div>`
      )
    )
  })
}

router.use('^/$', serverRenderer)

router.use(
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'))
)

app.use(router)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`SSR running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

categoryscreen.js:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import CategoryHeader from '../components/CategoryHeader'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions'

function CategoryScreen({ match }) {
    let ProductMatch = match.params.name

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList)
    const { products } = productList

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listProducts())
    }, [dispatch])

    return (
        <>
            <h3>{ProductMatch}</h3>
            <div>
                {products.filter(product => product.SubCategory == ProductMatch)
                    .map((product) => (
                        <Product product={product} />
                    ))
                }
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default CategoryScreen
```

ProductList action:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import {
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
} from '../constants/productConstants'


export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })

        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products')

        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message
                ? error.response.data.message : error.message
        })
    }
}
```

edit: added categoryscreen.js & redux action

Comment: Can you share the `CategoryScreen` as this component seems to not be handling the new URL?

Comment: @DrewReese added the categoryscreen

Comment: Thank you. Is it safe to assume that you correctly see the `name` (`ProductMatch`) match param update from "books" to "toys" with the route change? Can you clarify what state being lost you are referring to? The `productList`?

Comment: @DrewReese yes productmatch does update with route change. and data is being dispatched from productlist action. and i added the productList action to the post

Answer (score 0):

So at this point it's a bit unclear what the issue is. The URL changes, the component sees the new `ProductMatch` value, it is rerendered, it should filter the `productList` state by the `ProductMatch` category and remap the products.

The only piece I see missing here is providing a React key for the mapping. In the absence of the key React will basically use the child's index as the React key and since index `n` of the "books" subcategory will be the same as the index `n` of the "toys" subcategory I suspect React is simply bailing on rerendering your UI.

Provide a React key based on a unique property of each `product` being mapped, like `id`. If the products do not have this guarantee then I suggest augmenting your product data when it's processing into your redux state to add a GUID for this purpose.

```
{products.filter(product => product.SubCategory == ProductMatch)
  .map((product) => (
    <Product
      key={product.id} // <-- add React key
      product={product}
    />
  ))
}
```